# CSV Data preprocessing and reformatting python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a csv file with 22000 rows. I need to convert the csv file from the normal rows and columns format to rows with elements separated with commas using python. Elements with same id are to be in a row. New row is to be created for each id.

[Sample data before preprocessing is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUoxG.png)

[Dataset after processing is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajqsW.jpg)

I just want to delete the date column and display the elements with same id (in column B) inline.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where did all the apples etc. go? What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to count the occurrences of each item? And where is the timestamp coming from? Please post an example which **fully** covers your question.

Comment: Is my solution working for you?

Comment: Sorry guys. I had made a mistake in the positioning of the screenshots. Kindly have a look at the edited question.

Comment: @DheerajRavishankar - Don't put sample data as image. paste your sample data as text (so that easy to copy and paste to others).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this,

```
print pd.Series(sum(df.T.values.tolist(),[])).value_counts().reset_index()
```